# uncaught exceptional error in sml

Tags: sml, ml

I'am a beginner in s.m.l programming and  am trying to solve very simle problem in emacs(Ubuntu) that is written below

```
val x = 4
val y = 3
val z = x * y
```

I use above code and it showing this following error  :

```
"[use failed: Io: openIn failed on "f.sml", No such file or Directory]

uncaught exceptional error 

raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/interact.sml:24.14-24.28 "
```

so where did I do wrong ? please Help me. I know its a very simple Problem but am just a beginner.
Thank you :)

Comment: What did you enter into the REPL?  Presumably something along the lines of `use "f.sml"`.  Does `f.sml` exist in your current directory?

Comment: oooh Damn..!! thank you, now I understood. now  I created a file in gedit and saved it then i ran it in emacs then it worked..:) !! but what did i do wrong was first I created file in emacs and saved from there (Cntrl C & Cntrl S) and used it then it showed above error. so is it wrong to use from emacs like this ?

Comment: thank you now I understood :D

Comment: `C-c C-s` doesn't save - in SML mode it switches to the buffer where your REPL is. Save is `C-x C-s`.